# Starch Content of Dehydrated Potatoes

Tags: potatoes, dehydrating, starch

Good day!

I've been wondering this for years. 
I'm from Nova Scotia and we cook a Traditional meal called Rapure. 
The way it's made is by taking about 
15 lbs of potatoes and processing them to remove their liquid. 
Traditionally this was done by grating them by hand and squeezing out their juice. 
The modern way now is to process them through a juicer and collect the pulp inside
the juicers centrifuge.

This is then mixed with chicken broth in order to create a thick gelatinous mass. 
Many people believe that most of the starch is removed when the potatoes are "juiced."
However this thickening would suggest that most of the starch remains.

Could someone please clarify ?

Thanks!

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All potato cells contain starch. When you cut or rupture the cells, the starch is released

So grating a potato will release some starch, but only as much as the cut surface cells contain

Industrial potato starch processing use very large macerating machines and hot steam to break all the cells open, and release most of the starch

Comment: Awesome!You seem knowledgeable in this area - so I'll chance in asking you another question. How would one go ahead in measuring the starch content in the liquid extracted as well as the starch in the potato? Contact a local university ? Who does that kind of work ?

Comment: My knowledge on potatoes only extends to biology experiments as a teenager :-) And seeing industrial scale food processing machines! In Stack Exchange, always ask a new question, as a new question. Not sure SA will be best place for your question?